# SELECT DISTINCT skips distinct value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains most recent user searches that looks like this:

```
 id   username    entity      language       search_date
 44    kira        back         en          2017-09-26 17:41:35
 43    kira        back         en          2017-09-26 17:41:30
 42    kira        back         en          2017-09-26 17:41:29
 41    kira        babble       en          2017-09-26 17:41:01
 40    kira        baccalaurean en          2017-09-26 17:40:47
 39    kira        Time value   en          2017-09-26 17:39:34
 38    kira        bacarıq      en          2017-09-26 17:38:51
 37    yagami      quince       en          2017-09-26 17:38:35
```

I'm trying to fetch ten most rescent unique searches from this table and i'm doing it like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT entity, language
FROM users_searches
ORDER BY search_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

But for some wierd reson this query skips some values, for example it doesn't include `back` and starts from `babble`, can someone explain me why and how to achieve what i'm trying to do?

***UPDATE 1***
desired resullt should be something like this:
back, babble, baccalaurean, Time value, bacarıq, quince

Comment: So what result do you want? Post your desired result.

Comment: i want to select top ten results including each entity only one time. For some reason this query skips records, for example back, also updated my question for you to better see.

Comment: Your query seems to be correct, see [**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58c4e/1).

Comment: @Forward yeah i know, thats why i'm desperate, i just dont understand why

Comment: Have you try to run the query with `LIMIT`?  You have `order by search_date`, will it related to data?

Comment: what would if you `order by id desc`

Comment: intersting question, but you query is correct, it should work.

Comment: try with removing order by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT entity, language
FROM users_searches
ORDER BY search_date
DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Because `search_date` is not in the `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Does this do what you want?

```
select entity, language
from users_searches
group by entity_language
order by max(search_date) desc
limit 10;
```

Comment: I have fork the SQL fiddle here: [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/160491/1).  May I know the difference `order by max(search_date)` and `order by search_date`? Base on the result, it look like same. Thanks

Comment: @Prisoner . . . `max(search_date)` is correct.  The `order by` takes place after the aggregation, and you should not use "bare" columns (even if MySQL happens to allow it).

Comment: You originally attempted to use `select distinct` to summarize the rows but then require an order which isn't included in the result. So the answer - as shown here - is that you need to use `GROUP BY` instead. The advantage of this is you can then access aggregated values (e.g. max(search_date) or count(*) ) to order the final result by.